# Dynamically place buttons where there is a circle on background image

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-button

I am new android developer and trying to develop a game in android using eclipse IDE. Which has a game board like this
[image: http://i.imgur.com/bv149i8l.jpg?1]

**I just want to place the button where there is a circle.**

I hard-coded the buttons positions in xml using relative layout but because of different size of screens this solution is not working

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bani_qatar_board" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a8"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_a1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_a1"
    android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a7"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_a8"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b2"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_a1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_a1"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b1"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_a8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_b2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b8"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_a7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_b1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c2"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_b2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_b8"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c1"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_a8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_c2"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c8"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_b8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_c1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b3"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_b2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_a2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c3"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_c2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_c2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_b3"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c7"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_c8"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_c8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_c3"
    android:background="@drawable/blank"
    android:focusable="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b7"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_b8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_c7"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a6"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_a7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_a7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_b7"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c4"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_c3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_c3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_c3"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c5"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_c1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_c1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_c4"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_c6"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_c7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_c7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_c5"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b4"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_b3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_b3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_c4"
    android:background="@drawable/blank"
    android:paddingBottom="9dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b5"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_c5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_c5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_b4"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_b6"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_b7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_b7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_b5"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a3"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_b2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a4"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_b5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_b5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_a3"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a5"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_a6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_a6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_a4"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a2"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_b2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="86dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_c2"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infoDisplay"
    android:layout_width="175dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn_b1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_c5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_a1"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blank" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

Out put is 
[image: http://i.imgur.com/2tqrRXe.png?1]

**Issue :** You can clearly see buttons are not showing on circles.

**Note :** I don't want to used any game-engine right now for this purpose. I want to develop this game in eclipse.

Any suggestions how i can place buttons exactly on circle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll probably need some pattern recognition for this, if you don't know exactly where the circles are.

Comment: He knows where they are.

Comment: yes you are write i know the circles places on image But code wise i don't know where circles are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also hardcode the layout_height and layout_width of the relativeLayout. It's Background picture will be autosized to that layout size. Should work then for every display size.

Comment: thanks for suggestion let me check whether this solution works or not

Comment: Yes it works buttons position are not changed 
but now the problem is boardsize height and width is hardcoded so layout other part is showing black 
i want to show board on full screen of kindly see the image.
now what should i do thanks in advance
[link](http://i.imgur.com/APNvVeI.jpg)

Comment: Then you should do it programmatically. Use ur Layout with fill_parent again. Then in code, create buttons and set them depending on screen_sizes to correct positions. have a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/how-to-get-screen-dimensions

Comment: let us suppose i did get the screen_width and screen_height so how i will calculate the positions where the circles are?.

Comment: they are in some order... You have to trial and error. eg the first 3 are at (screenSizeX/3, screenSizeY/3), (2*screenSizeX/3, screenSizeY/3), (screenSizeX, screenSizeY/3) , then the other 2 lines. but you have to reattempt if they do not fit

Comment: ok got your point let me check whether this calculate correct value for different screen size pixels .

Comment: Although it is not a efficient solution but it will work.so +1
but i am still locking for good answer

Answer (score 0):

If you stretch background image on both dimensions without preserving AR, then you can use LinearLayout and arrange buttons by assigning layout_weight to them and invisible padding views.
But this may me very tedious and it may be better to calculate all positions in code.